# Docker Swarm - Can’t pull from private registry

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

I'm running a service on a Swarm cluster, thanks to `docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth` and this compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  builder-consumer:
    image: us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project/my/image:123
    stop_grace_period: 30m
    volumes:
      - [...]
    environment:
      - [...]
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
    secrets:
      - [...]
secrets:
  [...]
```

This works fine when I deploy, but when I add a worker node to the swarm later on, **the new worker can't pull the image** required to run the task. The system logs report this:

> level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: denied:
>   Permission denied for \123\" from request
>   \"/v2/my-gcloud-project/my/image/manifests/123\". "
>
> level=info msg="Translating \"denied: Permission denied for
>   \\"123\\" from request
>   \\"/v2/my-gcloud-project/my/image/manifests/123\\". \" to
>   \"repository us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project/my/image not found: does not
>   exist or no pull access\""
>
> level=error msg="pulling image failed" error="repository
>   us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project/my/image not found: does not exist or no
>   pull access" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=...
>   service.id=... task.id=...
>
> level=error msg="fatal task error" error="No such image:
>   us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project/my/image:123@sha256:..."
>   module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=... service.id=... task.id=...

However, when I manually run `docker pull` on that machine, it works fine, since every machine in the cluster is authenticated to my private Google Registry, thanks to `docker login`.

Thus my questions are:

- Why can't the added worker pull from the private registry?
- What does `--with-registry-auth` do exactly?

Thanks a lot

Note: the nodes are running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and the Docker version is:

```
Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Mon Apr  3 18:07:42 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: It looks like you've encountered a swarm mode issue. Have you checked their issues on GitHub and/or raised your own issue?

Comment: @bouga - did you solve this somehow? I have the same problem and looking for some workaround.

Comment: @Izydorr Nope, we simply moved away from swarm and use Kubernetes instead

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was not running the stack with "--with-registry-auth", so I shuted down the instances, and I started again the manager with that option, and now it works

Comment: As I said, I also deploy with `--with-registry-auth` and it works at first, but when I add a VM to the swarm (by joining as a worker), it fails to pull the services images due to a "Permission denied".

Comment: what about the TTL for ```CI_JOB_TOKEN```?