# Docker Swarm - Can't pull from private registry ON UPDATE, only works on initial DEPLOY

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am having issues with swarm worker nodes not updating images when doing either an update or deploy (on an existing stack).  The stack will always work when **created**

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004189/docker-swarm-can-t-pull-from-private-registry) only works on creation.

To reproduce the issue, do the following

1) create a container, something like httpd with an index.html, store it at **private-registry.example.com/path/image**

2) create test.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    test:
        # Use the build in the current pipeline
        image: private-registry.example.com/path/image
        deploy:
            replicas: 3
```

3) deploy stack

```
docker login private-registry.example.com
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=test.yml test
```

4) update the container, change some text

5) re-deploy the stack

```
docker login private-registry.example.com
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=test.yml test
```

the swarm manager will have the latest image, the swarm nodes will not.

```
docker service ps test_test

ID                  NAME                                  IMAGE                                    NODE                            DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR                              PORTS
j9497jwolee4        test_test.1       private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-slave-01.example.com   Running             Running 5 seconds ago
zsqxx3m0mpk3         \_ test_test.1   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-slave-01.example.com   Shutdown            Shutdown 7 seconds ago
sjjggcqmjcvo        test_test.2       private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-master.example.com     Running             Running 10 seconds ago
uyey60wv2vsc         \_ test_test.2   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-slave-01.example.com   Shutdown            Rejected 20 seconds ago   "No such image: private-registry..."
ttzvf4j3whk3         \_ test_test.2   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-slave-01.example.com   Shutdown            Rejected 25 seconds ago   "No such image: private-registry..."
x77e3r46zl1j         \_ test_test.2   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-master.example.com     Shutdown            Rejected 31 seconds ago   "No such image: private-registry..."
5a7lywn6zycz         \_ test_test.2   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-master.example.com     Shutdown            Rejected 36 seconds ago   "No such image: private-registry..."
qp1acqgthl33        test_test.3       private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-slave-02.example.com   Running             Running 11 seconds ago
osyn19o6c30j         \_ test_test.3   private-registry.example.com/path/image   swarm-master.example.com     Shutdown            Shutdown 12 seconds ago
```

**WORKAROUND**
This pulls the lastest image everytime without issue.

```
docker login private-registry.example.com
docker stack rm test
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file=test.yml test
```

**System**

```
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: I have the same problem, so still no answers or help?

Comment: http://kubernetes.io is likely the best answer, haven't switched yet.

Comment: Yes, I am switching to Kubernetes. But it is more complicated than docker swarm.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to check docker image digest by using `--resolve-image never`. Looks it like works.

> docker stack deploy --prune --with-registry-auth --resolve-image never -c docker-compose.yml xxxx

Comment: I think this can cause deployment of a bad image version